# oracle query to get the sum of column for different values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to get the sum of particular column

I want oracle query to get the sum of column "timespend" for each scenarios in (S_1, S_4, S_5, S_8) where name is equals to B

```
name id scenario timespend
A   123  S_1     2
A   123  S_1     5
A   123  S_3    6.3
B   124  S_1    3
B   124  S_1    8.9
B   124  S_1    5
B   124  S_1    4
B   124  S_5    1.23
B   124  S_5    56
B   124  S_5    8
B   124  S_8    9
B   124  S_8    4
C   125  S_8    6
D   126  S_2    9
D   126  s_4    5
D   126  s_4    6.2
D   126  s_4    7
E   127  S_1    8
E   127  S_1    1
```

I have used below query but its returning with sum of column timespend

```
select sum(timespend),
       scenario
from   table1
where  scenario in ('s_1','s_3','s_4','s_5','s_8')
and    name = 'B'
group by scenario
```

output of the query is

```
sum(timespend) scenario
-------------- --------
154.63          s_1
154.63          s_5
154.63          s_8
```

Expected output is

```
sum(timespend) scenario
-------------- --------
20.9            s_1
65.23           s_5
19              s_8
```

Can anyone help me to get the expected output as like mentioned above?

Comment: Can you please post the output of your query and the output you need?

Comment: You want the sum of timespend and you're getting the sum of timespend. I'm very confused now.

Comment: I have updated my query. i want the sum of timespend for set of scenarios that look similar for name B. but i m getting sum for all scenarios

Comment: Your query looks correct.

Comment: Are you sure that your query gives the result you posted?

Comment: yes my query returns the result what i have posted

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an issue with your query (although your expected output for scenario S_8 is wrong, plus you used lower case s in your where clause):

```
with table1 as (select 'A' name, 123 id, 'S_1' scenario, 2 timespend from dual union all
                select 'A' name, 123 id, 'S_1' scenario, 5 timespend from dual union all
                select 'A' name, 123 id, 'S_3' scenario, 6.3 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_1' scenario, 3 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_1' scenario, 8.9 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_1' scenario, 5 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_1' scenario, 4 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_5' scenario, 1.23 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_5' scenario, 56 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_5' scenario, 8 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_8' scenario, 9 timespend from dual union all
                select 'B' name, 124 id, 'S_8' scenario, 4 timespend from dual union all
                select 'C' name, 125 id, 'S_8' scenario, 6 timespend from dual union all
                select 'D' name, 126 id, 'S_2' scenario, 9 timespend from dual union all
                select 'D' name, 126 id, 'S_4' scenario, 5 timespend from dual union all
                select 'D' name, 126 id, 'S_4' scenario, 6.2 timespend from dual union all
                select 'D' name, 126 id, 'S_4' scenario, 7 timespend from dual union all
                select 'E' name, 127 id, 'S_1' scenario, 8 timespend from dual union all
                select 'E' name, 127 id, 'S_1' scenario, 1 from dual)
-- end of mimicking your table1 with data in it. See SQL below:
select sum(timespend),
       scenario
from   table1
where  scenario in ('S_1','S_3','S_4','S_5','S_8')
and    name = 'B'
group by scenario
order by scenario;

SUM(TIMESPEND) SCENARIO
-------------- --------
          20.9 S_1     
         65.23 S_5     
            13 S_8
```

Perhaps, judging from the fact that some of the scenario data in your sample data are in lowercase and you mentioned you were looking for the`set of scenarios that look similar`, you might want the following instead?

```
select sum(timespend),
       upper(scenario) scenario
from   table1
where  upper(scenario) in ('S_1','S_3','S_4','S_5','S_8')
and    name = 'B'
group by upper(scenario)
order by upper(scenario);
```

Comment: I got results for below query  as expected. Thank you                                                               select sum(timespend), scenario from table1 where name = 'B' and scenario in ('S_1','S_3','S_4','S_5','S_8')
group by scenario
order by scenario

Comment: @surendar: this seems the same query you posted in your question; isn't it?

Comment: @Aleksej looks like it to me! Obviously, there are gremlins in the OP's database or something! *{;-)